# The [term] tag has been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/term) tag has the following usage guidance:

> May refer to: 1) Term (language) or Terminology, 2) Term (time), 3) Technical term, 4) Scientific terminology or 5) Telecom Enforcement Resource and Monitoring.

A few examples of questions that use this tag:

- The `term` command in Vim/Neovim
- Looking for the right programming terminology
- Looking for specific natural language terms in Wordpress
- Tera Term Language

Given how ambiguous this tag is, I think we should just burninate it.

From the burnination criteria:

- **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?** Definitely not unambiguous - the tag Wiki lists several possible uses, none of which are more valid than the rest.
- **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?** That depends on the meaning. Pure terminology questions are generally not received well here. Other meanings are on-topic though.
- **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?** Not really - there are too many possible meanings for it.
- **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?** Absolutely not - I've listed several possible meanings above, and the tag Wiki lists several more. All of these meanings are equally valid.

Comment: Yeah, burn it to hell.

Comment: When I see [tag:term], the first thing I think of is some terminal-related module; think [py-term](https://pypi.org/project/py-term/), [term](https://pypi.org/project/term/), [term-forecast](https://pypi.org/project/term-forecast/), [term (again)](https://crates.io/crates/term), [ansi_term](https://crates.io/crates/ansi_term), the list goes on. Oddly enough, that isn't even in the tag description! Also, why does it have a difference between "terminology" and "_scientific_ terminology"? This isn't Science SE. Burninate it. Terminate it. So it can't **return**-inate-it.

Comment: One of [the listed definitions for the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/term/info) is "Term, Iran, a village in Mazandaran Province, Iran" - Why is _that_ part of the tag wiki?! At least the other ones are at least _in some way_ related to technology/programming. And it's been that way since 2016 [when it was approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13108621). Certainly, get rid of it. It is _way_ to broad.

Comment: @cocomac -- it's like they closed their eyes and threw darts at the Wikipedia disambiguation page for "term"...

Comment: We have a [tag:terminology] tag for technical terminology, so uses of [term] for that can be re-tagged, if anyone wants to get started on that.  Also, wow, I find it hilarious that this tag's own usage guidance suggests 3 incompatible meanings (and two redundant ones).

Comment: @cocomac One of the other listed meanings is "a human head and bust that continues as a square tapering pillar-like form" , which is also blatantly off-topic.

Comment: Only one thing comes to mind when I see [TERM](https://linux.die.net/man/7/term), and that relates to terminal. If users are expected to rely upon the tag wiki for usage (not that most new users know tags have a wiki), then what to do when the tag wiki is useless? Tag was [rejected twice](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13108621) : "Too much information - includes irrelevant definitions" & "Direct copy and a bunch of irrelevant entries" and yet approved by members who _should_ know better. And then it took over 5.5 for someone to call it out! Something's fundamentally broken!

Comment: @IanW the tag management is lopsided. It is easy to create a tag, but to remove it is impossible.

Comment: @AlexanderNied It appears that [that's exactly what they did](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term). A lot of it is literally word-for-word plagiarized from the Wikipedia disambiguation page.

Comment: @cocomac That's explained in the description itself: it's a _'Full list from Wikipedia'_. Possibly from around 2016 (compare [this version](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Term&oldid=742786898) from 5 October 2016). Somebody copied the full list from the Wikipedia's disambiguation page without a single thought about the purpose of their action.

Comment: @CiaPan In theory, the review should have been rejected. I’m not exactly sure why it was approved, but in theory the review process should prevent issues like this

Comment: @cocomac It looks like the perpetrator may have had enough rep to do a unilateral edit.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13108621

Comment: @cocomac Looks like you're correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/term) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Progress:

The [term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/term) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=term),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bterm%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bterm%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bterm%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bterm%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of burnination](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=416678)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/term) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/term) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/term) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.